# Conditional query always set data to false in room database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a local database that contains descriptions of recipees.

In the app the user can bookmark a recipee, I would like to update the corresponding value in the database which should be in my understanding a conditional query (so for instance if the user first click on the favorite icon, the value must be set to true and if he click again the value must be set to false in the database).

I make some research and I ended with a query like this:

```
@Query("UPDATE recipee SET favorite = CASE WHEN favorite = 0 THEN favorite = 1 ELSE favorite = 0 END WHERE name = :name")
void updateFavorite(String name);
```

The problem is that the value is always set to false and I don't understand why, it never sets to value to true. I don't know if there a problem with my query. If someone could enligth me on this matter.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your favorite to opposite of the current value. So use `NOT`

```
@Query("UPDATE recipee SET favorite = NOT favorite WHERE name = :name")
void updateFavorite(String name);
```

This will set favorite to true if it's false and vice versa.